# date format conversion ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, date

I think this says it all:

```
irb(main):014:0> DateTime.strptime("4/23/1967", "%m/%d/%y").to_s
=> "2019-04-23T00:00:00+00:00"
```

2019 comes up as the year?

i have a couple of different date formats:

`4/23/1967`

`3-3-1985`

I'd like to standardize them both to display in the first format (with slashes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%y` takes the year in 2 digits, so 19. Then DateTime assumes it's 2019. You need `%Y`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you've written `%y` where you meant `%Y`. Date format strings are case-sensitive.

```
irb(main):014:0> DateTime.strptime("4/23/1967", "%m/%d/%y").to_s
=> "2019-04-23T00:00:00+00:00"
```

but

```
irb(main):014:0> DateTime.strptime("4/23/1967", "%m/%d/%Y").to_s
=> "1967-04-23T00:00:00+00:00"
```